# Parse query in cloud code not working after migrating to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-cloud-code

I have migrated my Parse app to Heroku as per the migration guide on the Parse blog. Things seem to work fine except running a query in my cloud code. Here is my code:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Item", function(request) {
    //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); //Uncomenting this line yields the same error

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var prevAssigneeId = request.object.get("prevAssignee").id;
    var assigneeId = request.object.get("assignee").id;

    query.get(prevAssigneeId, { // <-- Results in an error
        success: function(prevAssignee) {
            console.log("Fetch prevAssignee: Success");
            query.get(assigneeId, {
                success: function(assignee) {
                    console.log("Fetch assignee: Success");

                    // Do something with the fetched users!
                },
                error: function(object, error) {
                   console.log("Query for assignee: ");
                   console.log(error);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.log("Query for prevAssignee: ");
            console.log(error); //<-- Error is logged here
        }
    });
});
```

**Error**

`ParseError { code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }`

This cloud code used to run fine when hosted on Parse. But after migrating I'm getting the above error. Other cloud code that does not use ParseQuery still work fine.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

**UPDATE**

Still not able to find a fix for this so I tried changing the code to the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Item", function(request) {

    console.log("Executing afterSave");

    function findUser(user_id) {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        //Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey();
        return query.get(user_id);
    }

    var prevAssigneePromise = findUser(request.object.get("prevAssignee").id);
    var assigneePromise = findUser(request.object.get("assignee").id);

    var promises = [prevAssigneePromise, assigneePromise];

    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(prevAssignee, assignee) {

        //Do something here!
        console.log("This line was executed!");

    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Now I noticed the following behavior:

- Run as is, it produces the same error: `[ ParseError { code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }, ParseError { code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' } ]`
- If I uncomment `Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey();`, there are no errors, but wont execute anything in the success block either i.e. log "This line was executed!". I can confirm that logging itself is working because other `console.log(...)` statements work.

Just FYI: `Item` is a Parse class with columns `assignee` and `prevAssignee` being columns that are pointers to `_User`s.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use

query.get(prevAssigneeId, {
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function(prevAssignee) {

Comment: @jiawen This didn't work, I tried a different approach which also didn't work (see my updated code). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
query.get(prevAssigneeId, {
    useMasterKey: true
    success: function(prevAssignee) {
        console.log("Fetch prevAssignee: Success");

    }
}
```

Comment: I am also getting an error in all my queries that use master key, but the error object is undefined.